# How can I keep my anchor tag menu from jumping to the top of the page on open or close of menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, anchor

I have a navigation menu that is using anchor tags. I am making a one-page website but the navigation on the mobile menu scrolls to the section and then keeps jumping back to the top when I open or close it. I've tried return false and preventDefault and nothing is working. I've read through many other similar questions and none of the answers seem applicable to this bit of code. All of my sections are built the same as the one I've posted. I know it's gotta be a simple answer but I'm having a block. Thank you in advance!

```
        <nav>
            <ul id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#bio">About the Developer</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
    <div class="home" id="main">
        <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
        <h1>This is the content.</h1>
        <section id="home">
            <h2>Home</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla rhoncus ultricies leo hendrerit fringilla. Donec vestibulum ut arcu eget porttitor. Sed eget dictum diam. Pellentesque et libero vitae eros molestie accumsan. Quisque ante sem, tristique vitae justo eget, rhoncus dictum ipsum. Suspendisse gravida volutpat justo, non auctor quam feugiat id. Aenean dapibus eget sem sit amet rhoncus. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse ac ex diam.</p>
        </section>
```

---

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    return false;
}


let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a");
let mainSections = document.querySelectorAll("main section");

let lastId;
let cur = [];

window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
   let fromTop = window.scrollY;

  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);

    if (
  section.offsetTop <= fromTop &&
  section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop
) {
  link.classList.add("current");
} else {
  link.classList.remove("current");
}
  });
});
```

UPDATE:

It has something to do with either the scripts, the fixed property, or the anchor tag. I have no idea how to go about keeping the page from jumping when I open and close the menu on mobile though. I've been researching this for hours now and am getting incredibly frustrated.

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

body {
    display: block;
}

header {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    width: 95vw;
    height: 50vh;
}

header img {
    max-height: 50vh;
}

.hamburger {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #213c50;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

nav ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 25px; 
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding-inline-start: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
    background-color: #213c50;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    size: 20px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#main {
    padding: 1rem;
}

#main h1, h2, p {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding-left: 3rem;
}

section {
    padding: 2rem;
    padding: bottom 20rem;
    margin: 0 0 3rem 0;
}

#home {
    min-height: 50vh;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #213c50;
}

#projects {
    min-height: 50vh;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fb806f;
}

#blog {
    min-height: 50vh;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #53a181;
}

#bio {
    min-height: 50vh;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fb806f;
}

#contact {
    min-height: 50vh;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #213c50;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you inlclude the CSS applied to these elements? So the code provided above can work when testing.

Comment: Updated it! Thank you